# How to use Drools decision tree in mongodb or any other rule engine

Tags: mongodb, drools, rule-engine

I have to store plenty of rules in my data base nearly 100k thousand.

and these rules can be modified , deleted and added dynamically, also my solution is HA(same application will run inmultiple instance ) hence instead of using Drools decision tree sheet (csv or xl) I have to use mongoDB.

**So is there any adapter for drool to work with mongoDB ?**

**is there drool working memory limitation when it related number of rules  ?**

**Will Drool supports below kind of decision checks ?**

```
 OSType   DeviceType  Make     year     Country    Value 
    (attr1)   (attr2)   (attr3)   (attr4)  (attr5)   (result)
    BADA        Galaxy   Samsung   2014     IN        100
    Android              Samsung   2015     China     150
                J7       Samsung   2018     IN        80
    Android     Note10   Samsung   2019               500 
    IOS         I7       APPLE              USA       1100 
    IOS                            2019               1000
```

now if data to rule is

```
OStype=Android,DeviceType=Note10, Make=Samsung, year=2019 Country=IN

in this case I have to return 500, as country is empty so I have to ignore from rule check 


OStype=IOS,DeviceType=I11, Make=APPLE, year=2029 Country=US

in this case I have to return 1000
```

Comment: If there is a working memory limitation, you're nowhere near it. I maintained a service with ~1.4 million rules and it was still responding within 30-100 ms.

Comment: Drool with mongodb (sql)? If so can you pls help me how to store the rule decision tree in mongodb..

Comment: No, these were straight up DRL. Once you get the rules read into a trie in memory they look the same.

Comment: Is there any Drool plugin to store drls in mongo db or SQL?

Comment: No clue. My company stored them pre-compiled in a SQL database and read them into memory on service startup. That's just something we built on our own though. If you mean _executing_ in the database, that's really not drools but some sort of query that you'd build yourself.